# "Access to an object's fields is only permitted within its methods" using callSoapService in Matlab

Tags: matlab, soap, methods, wsdl

I am using SOAP protocol to get response from a website using Matlab codes. my code is as below

```
createClassFromWsdl('https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/services/WebGate/wsdl');

obj = PaymentGatewayImplementationService;

PaymentRequest(obj,'9b9eef82-7cde-11e7-b794-000c295eb8fc', 100 ,'comment','','','www.google.com')
```

when I Run this code, an error occured as below:

'Access to an object's fields is only permitted within its methods'

How can I solve this problem ?

when I replace obj.endpoint in PaymentRequest with 'https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/services/WebGate/service', another error occures as follow:

'java.net.SocketException: Connection reset'

Comment: Please see: [mcve]

Comment: @excaza It's edited